# Get Attribute of Dynamic string

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, attributes

I have this container:

```
  <Div id="ListContainer">
```

I append these data to it :

```
 ' <a class="lesson" subjectID="'+sbj_ID+'"><b>
  <span class="lesson_subject">' + sbj_Name + '</span></b></a> ';
```

I want to put the value of sbj_ID & sbj_Name in a variable.

```
    localStorage['SubjectID']= "value of sbj_ID";
    localStorage['SubjectName']="value of sbj_Name";
```

But I can't access them.

I tried :

```
     $('#ListContainer').find('.lesson').attr('subjectID')
     $('#ListContainer .lesson').children[0].getAttribute('SubjectID')
     $('#ListContainer .lesson').children[2].innerHTML;
```

But they didn't work.

Comment: I would help if you post the generated HTML code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you are appending the string, but the following is a working example:

```
var sbj_ID = 3;
var sbj_Name = "test";

var str = '<a class="lesson" subjectID="'+sbj_ID+'"><b><span class="lesson_subject">' + sbj_Name + '</span></b></a>';

$("#ListContainer").append(str);

alert($('#ListContainer').find('.lesson').attr('subjectID'));
```

[**-- See Demo --**](http://jsfiddle.net/8KkUc/)

I'm also not sure how `LocalStorage` is being used, but you should set the variables as the value, not the strings you have used:

```
localStorage['SubjectID']= sbj_ID;
localStorage['SubjectName']= sbj_Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
localStorage['SubjectID']= $('.lesson').attr('subjectID');

localStorage['SubjectName']=$('.lesson_subject').text();
```

or

```
 localStorage['SubjectName']=$('.lesson_subject').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
localStorage['SubjectID'] = $('.lesson').attr('subjectID');
localStorage['SubjectName'] = $('.lesson_subject').text();
```